# Use ctrlp.vim to browse files without recursing?

Tags: vim, ctrlp

Is there any way to use ctrlp.vim to browse files without recursing through all the possible directories?

For example, so that it can usefully be used from a home directory (or other large directory):

```
<c-p>
co<tab> " matches ~/code directory
code/pyt<tab> " matches python-2.7.6
code/python-2.7.6/R<tab> " matches README
```

Note: setting `g:ctrlp_max_depth` doesn't help here, since there isn't any obvious way to ask ctrlp to re-scan a directory once it has been matched (ex, in the above example, the `code/` directory might be matched, but no sub-directories will be found).